# Powershell - how to add exclusions for defender

Tags: powershell, windows-11, windows-defender

I need to set folder exclusion for defender using powershell. The problem is that folder has dot in its name `../.m2/..` (folder for IDE IntelliJ IDEA). If I am trying to create this exclusion with this command:

```
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "%HOMEPATH%/.m2"
```

defender takes it as file exclusion not as path, check this screenshot
[defender exclusions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGwmb.png)

I have tried different modifications of command which I have mentioned above but still same problem

```
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "%HOMEPATH%\.m2"
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "%HOMEPATH%\\.m2"
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "%HOMEPATH%\.\.m2"
...
```

Could someone help me, how to do it?

I am also trying to set it to another computers in my company using SCCM, where is same problem. I am not able to put the path with var like ${env:HOMEPATH} etc which is mentioned in answer - invalid path
[SCCM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9P7u.png)

Comment: Does it work if you add a \ at the end?

Comment: @AndrewMorton no, I have tried to add `Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "%HOMEPATH%\.m2\resources"` It also takes as file no folder...

Comment: It isn't clear to me if you understood what I meant: for example, use `Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "%HOMEPATH%\.m2\"` - notice that the last character is a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Defender doesn't recognize the path because it doesn't perform variable expansion dynamically; it wants the invoking program to expand it to an exact path.

The syntax for variable expansion in PowerShell is not `%var%` but `$var` or `${var}`, similar to Bash. Specifically, *environment* variables are accessed as `$env:FOO`, such as `$env:HOMEPATH`.

Additionally, HOMEPATH does not include the drive letter – you almost certainly want to use HOMEDRIVE together with it, e.g. `${env:HOMEDRIVE}${env:HOMEPATH}\.m2`.

Not all programs use the "home" path – often they actually store data in USERPROFILE, and the home location *may* be different from the profile location. `(Resolve-Path ~\.m2)` is another way to expand profile-relative paths, mostly equivalent to `$env:USERPROFILE\.m2`.

Comment: Yes, in powershell on my computer it works. However I am trying to set it also by SCCM to another computers in our company, and there is examples of path with variables like %windir% etc... I have edited my post.

Comment: @rumcajs - You will have to identify the configuration changes required for your script to work. Your script as provided in your question isn’t correct or should be expected to work necessarily per this answer